# Sort values from an array first based on another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

I want to sort values first depending on the order based on another array.

```
$countries = explode(',', 'AF,AL,DZ,AS,AD,FR,AO,AI,AQ,GB');
$popular   = explode(',', 'FR,GB');
```

I from `$countries` I want the values defined in `$popular` to form an array like this:

```
$ordered = ['GB,FR,AF,AL,DZ,AS,AD,AO,AI,AQ']
```

Thanks

Comment: you need to write the custom code for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

**check working demo here** : https://eval.in/873974

```
$countries = explode(',', 'AF,AL,DZ,AS,AD,FR,AO,AI,AQ,GB');
$popular   = explode(',', 'FR,GB');
sort($popular); // sort to manage order

// remove common element from $countries and merge with $popular
$ordered = array_merge($popular,array_diff($countries, $popular));     
echo "<pre>";
print_r($ordered);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php 
        $arr= array();
        $countries = explode(',', 'AF,AL,DZ,AS,AD,FR,AO,AI,AQ,GB');
        $popular   = explode(',', 'FR,GB');
        $total_popular = count($popular);
        $total_countries = count($countries);

        for ($i=0; $i < $total_popular; $i++) { 
            if (in_array($popular[$i], $countries)) {
                $arr[]=$popular[$i];
            }
        }
        for ($j=0; $j < $total_countries; $j++) { 
            if (! in_array($countries[$j], $arr)) {
                $arr[]=$countries[$j];
            }
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($arr);

        ?>
```

Your desired output of this code is

[image]